# Turn off smooth scrolling in Slack

Tags: slack, user-interface

In Slack, when I'm browsing a channel, if I press <kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd>, the channel content scrolls smoothly, i.e. the content moves one screen line at a time and it takes about one second to perform the operation. Strangely, I only have this problem with <kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd>: other methods of scrolling, such as <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>, the mouse wheel or clicking on the scroll bar to scroll by one page at a time work instantly.

I have smooth scrolling disabled in my browser. I tried with both Firefox and Chrome.

I presume this will take some custom Javascript but I haven't found an existing userscript and I can't figure out what's causing the smooth scrolling.

How do I turn off Slack's smooth scrolling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This userscript kills the smooth scrolling.  I tested it with Violentmonkey in Chrome.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Slack: disable smooth scrolling on PgUp/PgDown/Home/End
// @namespace   slack_disable_smooth_scrolling
// @description Disables the smooth scrolling
// 
// @match       https://*.slack.com/*
// @version     1.0.0
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev) {
    if(ev.key == "PageDown" || ev.key == "PageUp" || ev.key == "Home" || ev.key == "End") {
        if(ev.target && ev.target.classList && ev.target.classList.contains("ql-editor")) {
            document.getElementById("msgs_scroller_div").focus();
        }
        ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: This works in Firefox with Tampermonkey, thank you! However, not being able to use PgUp/PgDn while the focus is on the input box is annoying. Is there a more convenient way to switch to the message section than Ctrl+\` followed by Tab, which is pretty awkward and unmemorable?

Comment: @Gilles Fixed to allow scrolling while in the input box (tested Violentmonkey in Chrome again), let me know if it doesn't work or breaks some other functionality.